# I have built a CNN for detecting human faces . From the very first epoch I am getting higher accuracy. What might be the reason for it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, face-recognition

The training data set consists of face images taken from youtube faces database labelled as one and non face images are taken from 256Object categories 25k images are chosen for both positive and negative data. so totally 50k for training and another 10k images is taken from yooutube faces and 256 object categories which are not repeated.

The problem is I am getting 99% accuracy after just 12k iterations in first epoch itself and I am printing cost value also it is also starts from very high value like 596014.000 like that. When it is tested against the other face images it performs very badly.
[cost vs epoch graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dekes.png)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import read_data
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import os
import graph_plotter as gp

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 30
batch_size = 100
display_step = 5

# tf Graph input
input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 27, 31, 3])
output_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) #dropout (keep probability)

# Getting train and test data
train_data, train_label , test_data, test_label = read_data.getData()

def conv2d(x, w, bias, k=1):
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides=[1, k, k, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, bias)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)


# Performs max pooling on the convolution layer output
def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
   return tf.nn.max_pool(x, 
   ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],       
   padding='SAME')

# Weights generated randomly according to layer
weights = {

   # Conv 4*4 , 1 input , 32 outputs
   'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([4, 4, 3, 32])),

   # Conv 3*3 , 32 inputs , 32 outputs
  'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 32, 64])),

  # Conv 5*6 , 64 input , 128 outputs
  'wc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 6, 64, 128])),

  # Conv 1*1 , 128 inputs , 256 outputs
  'wc4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 1, 128, 256])),

  # Conv 1*1 , 256 inputs , 256 outputs
  'wc5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 1, 256, 512])),

  # Output Layer 7*8*256 inputs and 1 output ( face or non-face )
  'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*8*512, 1]))
  }

 biases = {

   'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
   'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
   'bc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128])),
   'bc4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256])),
   'bc5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([512])),
   'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
 }

 def model(x, weight, bias, dropout):

 # Layer 1
 conv1 = conv2d(x, weight['wc1'], bias['bc1'])
 conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

 # Layer 2
 conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weight['wc2'], bias['bc2'])
 conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

 # Layer 3
 conv3 = conv2d(conv2, weight['wc3'], bias['bc3'])

 # Layer 4
 conv4 = conv2d(conv3, weight['wc4'], bias['bc4'])

 # Layer 5
 conv5 = conv2d(conv4, weight['wc5'], bias['bc5'])

 #conv5 = tf.nn.dropout(conv5, dropout)

 # Flattening data
 intermediate = tf.reshape(conv5, shape=[-1, 7*8*512])

 # Output Layer
 output = tf.add(tf.matmul(intermediate, weight['out']), bias['out'])
 return output

 pred = model(input_data, weights, biases, keep_prob)

 l2_loss = 0.001*(
            tf.nn.l2_loss(weights.get('wc4')) +
            tf.nn.l2_loss(weights.get('wc5')) +
            tf.nn.l2_loss(weights.get('out')))

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
 pred,    output_data)) + l2_loss

tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
correct_pred = tf.equal(
tf.greater(sigmoid_output, 0.5),      tf.greater(output_data, 0.5))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

y_p = tf.cast(tf.greater(sigmoid_output, 0.5), tf.int32)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
tf.add_to_collection('y_p', y_p)
tf.add_to_collection('pred', pred)
tf.add_to_collection('x', input_data)
tf.add_to_collection('y', output_data)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    train_data_minibatches = [train_data[k:k + batch_size] 
    for k in   range(0, len(train_data), batch_size)]
    train_label_minibatches = [train_label[k:k + batch_size] 
    for k in range(0, len(train_label), batch_size)]
    step = 0
    batch_count = 0
    avg_cost_list = []
    avg_accuracy_list = []
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print('Epoch '+epoch.__str__())
        cost_list = []
        accuracy_list = []
        for batch_x, batch_y in zip(
            train_data_minibatches, train_label_minibatches):
            batch_count += 1
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={
            input_data: batch_x,  output_data: batch_y,
                                         keep_prob: 0.75})
            # if epoch % display_step == 0:
            loss, acc, output = sess.run([cost, accuracy, sig],
            feed_dict={input_data: batch_x,                                                                    output_data: batch_y,                                                                    keep_prob: 0.75})

            cost_list.append(loss)
            accuracy_list.append(acc)

            print("Iter " + str(step * batch_size) +" Loss "+ "{:.5f}".format(loss)+ ", Training Accuracy= " +
                  "{:.5f}".format(acc))
            step += 1
        average_cost = sum(cost_list) / len(cost_list)
        average_acc = sum(accuracy_list) / len(accuracy_list)

        avg_cost_list.append(average_cost)
        avg_accuracy_list.append(average_acc)

        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            test_acc, y_pred = sess.run([accuracy, y_p], feed_dict={input_data: test_data,
                                                        output_data: test_label,
                                                        keep_prob: 0.75})

            print(metrics.confusion_matrix(test_label, y_pred))
            print("Testing Accuracy : " + "{:.5f}".format(test_acc))
            print("Optimization finished !!")

    # Saving cost Vs epoch graph, and accuracy Vs epoch graphs.
    gp.cost_vs_epoch(avg_cost_list)
    gp.accuracy_vs_epoch(avg_accuracy_list)

    save_path = saver.save(sess=sess, save_path=save_path, write_meta_graph=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.greater(sigmoid_output, 0.5),
                        tf.greater(output_data, 0.5))
```

is likely to be wrong. Your code seems not to have `sigmoid_output`, but only `pred`.

If that is not the problem, I would look into `train_data`. How many "True" labels > 0.5 do you have? How many labels which evaluate to false do you have?